# how to get call log and SMS history in jailbreak iPhones running iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, jailbreak

I am trying to get call log and SMS history in jailbroke iPhones in iOS 8, but I am not getting any path for iOS 8. I searched in google and asked on Ask Different and I found some code but it is only working in iOS 4. So please  help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sms: check "/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db"

call log: check "/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata"

Comment: Hey david, I am trying to get Call log but I am getting false when I am checking for /var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata

But true when I am checking /var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB

Can you help me in this ?